# Как получить json объект из класса с типами внутри?

Tags: javascript, json, классы

Мне нужно трансформировать класс в json объект

```
class ClassExamle {
        constructor(n) {
          this.name = n;
        }
    }
```

Я попробовал JSON.stringify(new ClassExample(1)) и результат был таким {"name":1} Но мне нужно написать функцию которая преобразует класс с типами внутри, вот так {"name": string} или вот так

```
Class Age {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age
        }
    }

console.log(convertClassInJSON(new Age(1))) // {"age": number}
```

Comment: а откуда преобразователь должен тип взять? угадать? и вообще зачем это всё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Age {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age
  }
}

function convertClassInJSON(e) {
  const ret = {};
  for (i of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)) {
    ret[i] = typeof e[i];
  }
  
  return JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(convertClassInJSON(new Age(1))); // {"age": number}
```

Comment: прикольно будет смотреться при `this.users = []`  вывод что users - object )))  технически это так, но фактически это массив)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, оставим это для изучения автору вопроса.

Comment: Его ждёт много сюрпризов))